# Get all customer and company replicas - webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, request

I'm trying to do web scraping on reclameaqui site ([www.reclameaqui.com.br](http://www.reclameaqui.com.br)).

```
import scrapy
from ..items import ComplaintItem
import json


class ComplaintScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "complaintScraper"  

    start_urls = [f"https://iosearch.reclameaqui.com.br/raichu-io-site-search-v1/query/companyComplains/10/{item}?company=98" for item in range(0,100,10)]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse, dont_filter=True)
  
    def parse(self, response):

        complaintItem = ComplaintItem()

        data = json.loads(response.text)
      
        for card in data['complainResult']['complains']['data']:
            complaintItem = ComplaintItem()
            complaintItem['id']               = card['id']
            complaintItem['title']            = card['title']   
            complaintItem['description']      = card['description']
            complaintItem['url']              = response.url
            yield complaintItem
```

I'd like to get all interactions (customer and company replica), but it is a kind of hash:

> interactions': ['kAg79krfcjNpAXZ5']

How can I get all customer and company replicas (I already have the complaint description)?

Comment: I\m getting that the `interactions` is an empty list...

Comment: It has to be empty if there is not customer or company replica.

Comment: By 'replica' you mean response. By 'hash'.. I haven't the faintest idea. Please use DeepL for translating, rather than google translate.

Comment: @Fillipe then direct us to a url that it's not empty in it

Comment: https://iosearch.reclameaqui.com.br/raichu-io-site-search-v1/query/companyComplains/10/10?company=98&status=ANSWERED&evaluated=bool:false . First interaction is: interactions":["hbKmKRq9n_625O7n"]